# how to render a component using *ngIf based on the value of the Token?

Tags: angular

I am using https://reqres.in/api/login for creating a page for login authentication.
The issue is that i want to display a navbar item only once login is done.Prior to that ,nothing should be displayed on the navbar item.
I have defined a service for login which is being called once login button is clicked.

```
public Login(login: Login):
  Observable<any>{
    return this.httpclient.post<any>('https://reqres.in/api/login',login,{responseType:"json"})
    .pipe(map(
      user=>{
        if(user){
            console.log(user)
          this.currentUserName=user;

        }

        return user;
      }
    )

    )
  }
```

the user value returned here is a token.
and in my app.component.html i am using the condition as

```
 <li class="navbar-item" *ngIf="loginservice.user == 'QpwL5tke4Pnpja7X4' "> 
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="dashboard" >Dashboard</a>    
    </li>
```

I want to render the dashboard only when login is done .How can it be done.

Comment: What does `loginservice` refers to?

Comment: Why not use `*ngIf="loginservice.user"` where `loginservice.user` is undefined when initialized and when it fails? Your dashboard will be hidden and you do not need to check for any specific token, only that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach:

Create a `user` property in component and try `*ngIf="user"`.

In LoginService:

```
public login(login: any) {
return this.httpclient
  .post<any>("https://reqres.in/api/login", login, { responseType: "json" })
}
```

In Component ts:

```
this.loginService.login(login as any).subscribe(
  user => {
    if (user) {
      console.log(user);
      this.user = user;
      this.currentUserName = user.name;
    }
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

HTML:

```
<li class="navbar-item" *ngIf="user"> 
  <a class="nav-link" routerLink="dashboard" >Dashboard</a>    
</li>
```

Hope this will help.